# Merging two similar c functions into one

Tags: c, function

I have two functions that look like the ones down below and I am trying to merge the two with a function called function3 however I don't want it to check the parameter 'function' everytime it enters the while loop as it is a very poor way to do it. I am wondering if I can merge the two with only one if statement.

```
void function1(){
    int value,a,b;
    while(condition){
        value=a*b;
    }

}

void function2(){
    int value,a,b;
    while(condition){

        value=a+b;
    }
}


//merge two functions 
void function3(int function){
    int value,a,b
    while(condition){
        if(function==1){
            value=a*b;
        }
        else{
            value=a+b;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `while` loop at all? That makes an infinete loop doing the same thing over and over again? Doesn't seem to make sense. Should just remove the `while` unless there is a strange reason for that. If that isn't actually representative of your real code then please update the question with a clearer example.

Comment: I'm afraid you've no choice but to use a condition to branch to apt group of instructions to execute. It's not like they're same, or even overlapping, superset/subset. You can refactor common code, if those functions are too long.

Comment: yeah, this is not the original code. I simplified it like this. In the original code a and b are changing inside the while loop and value is being passed to some other function..

Comment: Since these *clearly* aren't the real functions being used for speculation, only you can answer how/when/if they can be merged, and whether it makes sense to do it. To that, do not be quick to abandon the single-responsibility principle. Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from the code you posted what you intent to do, since you don't actually do anything with the values you calculated.

Aside, I think that you are looking for an *array of functions* or **an array of pointers to functions**.

You can use the variable `function` to access the function that you need, assuming it matches the array index of that function.

```
int function1(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}

int function2(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int (*f[])(int, int) = { function1, function2 };

void call_function(int function, int a, int b) {
    // check that "function" is within bounds of the array

    if (function < 0 || function >= sizeof(f) / sizeof(f[0])) {
        // handle out of bounds
    }

       // call appropriate function
    int ret_val = f[function](a, b);

    return;
}
```